# Define field with generic type using ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I just started playing with ByteBuddy and I am working on a couple examples in order to get the hang of it.

What I am trying to accomplish with this exercise is to replace some code that uses ASM, with ByteBuddy.

So far I have been successful when it comes to non-generic types. For example I can easily define a field for example like this

```
builder.defineField("names", List.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
```

if all I want to do is create a field of raw `List` type.

When it comes to introducing generics however, I am stuck.

Obviously the way I have defined the field (using a `Class`) means that the generic types are lost. Reading the [documentation](http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) (especially the `Working with generic types` part), I can't really figure out how  I would construct a List field if it has a known generic type, like for example if it's another POJO. Let's say I have the following POJO:

```
public class Dummy {
   private String name;

   //getters, setters
}
```

and I want to create a field of `List<Dummy>`, how would I accomplish such a task?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record: you know about type erasure, and the fact that the generated class doesn't know that a field is a List of specifically Dummy?

Comment: @GhostCat Sure thing! However there are some 'magical' cases where I **can** know the erased type (see Jackson for instance)

Comment: Of course the generated class knows about its generic field signature. Erasure means that the instance of a generic class does not know about its generic type. But it knows the generic types of its members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of providing a `Class<List>` to the defineField method, you can provide a `Type`. ByteBuddy has a helper class to create generic Types so you don't need to create an implementation yourself. I put it on a separate line to make it more visible.

```
    // Create List<Dummy> as Type
    Generic generic = TypeDescription.Generic.Builder
            .parameterizedType(List.class, Dummy.class).build();

    Class<? extends Example> loaded = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Example.class)
            .defineField("names", generic, Visibility.PRIVATE).make()
            .load(ByteBuddyEnhancer.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION).getLoaded();
```

One way of validating the field is actually set and contains the generic parameters would be this testcase

```
    Field field = loaded.getDeclaredField("names");
    Type fieldType = field.getGenericType();
    Assert.assertTrue(fieldType instanceof ParameterizedType);
    ParameterizedType genericFieldType = (ParameterizedType)fieldType;
    Assert.assertEquals(Dummy.class, genericFieldType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    System.out.println(genericFieldType.getRawType());
    System.out.println(genericFieldType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
```