# How to create parametrized class in byte-buddy?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

How to create parametrized class in byte-buddy?
For example:

```
    static public class SomeClass < T > {
      T value;
    }



    Class<?> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy()
                   .subclass(Object.class)
                   .defineField("value", ???, Modifier.PUBLIC)
                   .make()
                   .load(Main.class.getClassLoader())
                   .getLoaded();
```

Comment: Generics in java are intended for the compiler. There are no parameterized classes at runtime. Maybe this will help explain: [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: Does this help? [Define field with generic type using ByteBuddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864313/define-field-with-generic-type-using-bytebuddy)

Comment: There are of course generic types at runtime. The JVM does not process it but it is available as meta data that can be read using the reflection API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as:

```
new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class)
  .typeVariable("T")
  .defineField("value", TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.typeVariable("T").build(), Modifier.PUBLIC);
```